# Symbol for not conditionally independent

Tags: math-operators, statistics

I have previously used some code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154530/a-conditional-independence-symbol-that-looks-good-with-mid) to produce a symbol to represent the conditionally independence of some variables. Does anyone know a method for generating a symbol for `not conditionally independent`. That is, the symbol below but with a forward slash through the symbol netween `a` and `c`. Thank you.

some code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

% function for conditional independence - from link above    
\newcommand{\bigCI}{\mathrel{\text{\scalebox{1.07}{$\perp\mkern-10mu\perp$}}}}

a $\bigCI$ c $\mid$ b

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Use the `cancel` package?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. ***Please correct your code so that it compiles.***

Comment: You should use the code that utilizes `\mathpalette`, which allows you to just use `\not\independent` without problem.

Comment: @Werner No, `\not` works only for symbols as wide as `=`.

Comment: @cfr - thanks for the recommendation, updated. Werner, thank youalso, i shall look at this as well.

Comment: @egreg: I did consider `\centernot`. Using `\not` seemed better in the output when compared to `\centernot`. The stroke cut the vertical `\perp`s higher, which seemed better (in my opinion).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure about the advantage of scaling the symbol by 7%. I propose the definitions for both the scaled and unscaled symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,centernot}

% function for conditional independence - from link above
\newcommand{\bigCI}{\mathrel{\text{\scalebox{1.07}{$\perp\mkern-10mu\perp$}}}}
\newcommand{\nbigCI}{\centernot{\bigCI}}

\newcommand{\CI}{\mathrel{\perp\mspace{-10mu}\perp}}
\newcommand{\nCI}{\centernot{\CI}}

\begin{document}

$a \bigCI c \mid b$ and $a \nbigCI c \mid b$

$a \CI c \mid b$ and $a \nCI c \mid b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the quick answer- that looks great

Answer (score 5):

Rather than use built up symbols you can use a font with ⫫ (U+2aeb) such as stix

You can just use `\not` for the negation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}

$a \Vbar b \mid c $


$a \not\Vbar b \mid c $

\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this changes all fonts of the document.

Comment: @egreg it does although you could pull just that character from the font of that was needed.

Comment: Thank you David - i didn't even know it had a name <DOUBLE UP TACK>

Answer (score 3):

Say:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,cancel}
\begin{document}

% function for conditional independence - from link above
\newcommand{\bigCI}{\mathrel{\text{\scalebox{1.07}{$\perp\mkern-10mu\perp$}}}}
\newcommand{\nbigCI}{\cancel{\mathrel{\text{\scalebox{1.07}{$\perp\mkern-10mu\perp$}}}}}
a $\bigCI$ c $\mid$ b

a $\nbigCI$ c $\cancel{\mid}$ b

\end{document}
```

[image: cancelled relations]

Comment: For negating `\mid`, `amssymb` provides `\nmid`.

Comment: @egreg I only did that to show that you could use `\cancel` directly. But I don't think this is a good way of doing it anyway.