# Clash between amssymb and MnSymbol

Tags: boxes, marginnote, amssymb, mnsymbol

Following from another post
[Margin notes on both left and right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101553/margin-notes-on-both-left-and-right/316245#316245)
 I am having problems while using both MnSymbol and amssymb in the same document. It says `! LaTeX Error: Command`\centerdot' already defined.`

I cannot work without `amssymb`, but if I remove `MnSymbol` I get yet another error

```
! Undefined control sequence. \pointer ->\filledmedtriangleleft
```

Any idea how I could work around this issue?

If I remove `amssymb` I get `! Missing $ inserted. $ l.2` `\item M` ix all ingredients together. ?

I'm trying to use the following code proposed by Christian Hupfer

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*\mnote[3][0pt]{%
  \if l#2\reversemarginpar\def\pointer{\filledmedtriangleright}%
    \def\stackalignment{r}\fi%
  \if r#2\normalmarginpar\def\pointer{\filledmedtriangleleft}%
    \def\stackalignment{l}\fi%
  \marginpar{%
    \topinset{%
      \scalebox{1.5}{\textcolor{blue}{$\pointer$}}}{%
      \belowbaseline[-1.5\baselineskip-#1]{%
        \stackengine%
          {-5pt}%
          {\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{\parbox{1.8cm}%
            {\vspace{3pt}\raggedright#3}}}%
          {~\colorbox{white}{\sffamily Note}}%
          {O}%
          {l}%
          {F}%
          {F}%
          {S}%
        }%
      }{%
      3ex+#1}{%
      -2ex}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
this is a\mnote[2ex]{l}{some text for the mnote box} test%
\par\vspace{-\parskip}\mnote[1ex]{r}{both right and left}

\lipsum[3]
This is another test\mnote{r}{another mnote box test testing the
right side}

\lipsum[4]

Loads and loads of text that need amssymb to work
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me, and it cannot give rise to the error you quoted (there is no `\item Mix...` anywhere). Can you show us the actual code? From the error messages you are quoting I'd say that you are rather loading `MnSymbol` before `amssymb`.

Comment: I suspect you *don't* want to load the whole `MnSymbol`, because it changes ***all*** math symbols.

Comment: After extensive work, I managed to narrow it down. It seems that when using amssymb the `\checkmark` does not need to be in math environment (at least it never gave me an error before), but in MnSymbol it does.
And you were right, I had to load amsymb first

Comment: @egreg, yeah, loading just the symbols I need would have been ideal, but I have not figured out how yet. At least now I know what to do if I run into another symbol that fails, but if you know how to load just the symbols I need, that would help me understand the dynamics of '\LaTex' better

Comment: There are a number of answers on how to import just a few specified MnSymbol glyphs: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217986/standard-ams-sum-operator-using-mnsymbols/219282#219282, and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3631/is-there-a-standard-symbol-for-conditional-independence/246205#246205,

Answer (score 3):

Per my comments... import from `MnSymbol` just what is required.  You can uncomment the two `fonttable` lines to see that the desired glyph is in slot 202 of the `MnSymbolC` font family.

If you have many symbols to import from `MnSymbol`, my answer at [Is there a standard symbol for conditional independence?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3631/is-there-a-standard-symbol-for-conditional-independence/246205#246205) provides some macros for easing that process.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
% =============================================
%Import symbols from font MnSymbol without importing the whole package
% =============================================
\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolC}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolC5
  <6-7> MnSymbolC6
  <7-8> MnSymbolC7
  <8-9> MnSymbolC8
  <9-10> MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC10
  <12-> MnSymbolC12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolC-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolC-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolC-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolC-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolC-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolC-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyC} {U} {MnSymbolC}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\filledmedtriangleleft}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{202}
% =============================================
%\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\centering
$\mathbb{X}\filledmedtriangleleft\mathbb{Y}$
%\fonttable{MnSymbolC10}
\end{document}
```

[image]