# MnSymbol, amssymb and amsfonts

Tags: fonts, symbols, amsmath, mnsymbol

Is there still a conflict between MnSymbol and amssymb & amsfonts, or have the problems between them been resolved?

Confer: [Clash between amssymb and MnSymbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316249/clash-between-amssymb-and-mnsymbol)

Comment: It is unlikely that this will change.  `amssymb` and `amsfonts` are used in a production environment requiring stability.  I don't know the background of 'MnSymbol`, but it was clearly intended for a use where the original Computer Modern fonts didn't provide the desired "look".  The answers to the linked question offer good advice.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have a document where I use the three, and it crashes if I comment out one of them.

Comment: if you make an example and show the error rmessage you get and state which fonts you want then someone could help. Goven they are defining the same commands with different font sthere is obviously no general solution but you can certainly define specific symbols from whichever font you want.

Comment: Steven's answer there _is_ the resolution, what error did you get if you tried it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The document compiles, with a temporary error message, Error: Could not start the command: bibtex "Elements of Librationism 0".aux, if I us all three.

Comment: I can't see how bibtex is any way related to the math fonts.  Add a small complete example in your document and say what output you want. Note that the answer you link to loads the mnfont directly not via the package.

Comment: After making changes as recommended by @DavidCarlisle's comment, remove all existing `.aux` files and start again with a clean environment.

Comment: I was able to resolve the problem by substituting \anglebar (\ranglebar) under MnSymbol with \llparenthesis (\rrparenthesis) under usepackage{stmaryrd}. As adviced by @barbarabeeton, I deleted the old .aux file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Incidentally, the error message Error: Could not start the command: bibtex "Elements of Librationism 0".aux disappeared.

Comment: @Sapiens presumably deleting the aux file cleared the pipeline but it's not related to fonts.