# What's wrong with Libertine + MnSymbol + newtxmath?

Tags: packages, libertine, math-fonts, newtxmath, mnsymbol

There's something really wrong with this combination:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
  sdfsdfsldkfsld skdj sldkf sdsd
\begin{equation}
  \overbrace{p(\theta | x)}^{\text{posterior}} =
  \frac{\overbrace{p(x | \theta)}^{\text{likelihood}}\;
    \overbrace{p(\theta)}^{\text{prior}}}{p(x)},
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Instead of overbraces, some integrals occur:

[image: Bayes' theorem with wrong formatting]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you need MnSymbol?

Comment: @Davislor I have already decided I don't :) I just didn't like the product symbol with only Libertine & newtxmath and was trying out things. But I thought it'd make a useful answer anyway.

Comment: Then this might be useful as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174814/how-to-get-only-one-symbol-from-a-symbol-package/565640#565640

Comment: Thanks, I do in fact use a similar method described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246205/46356, with some tweaking for getting text and display variants right.

Comment: `MnSymbol` is specific for use with Minion as text font.

Answer (score 1):

To work together correctly, `newtxmath` needs to be loaded before `MnSymbol`:

```latex
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
```