# The `\dot` accent does not appear when using the document class `acmart` together with the `MnSymbol` package

Tags: symbols, accents, acmart, mnsymbol

The dot accent doesn't appear with the document class `acmart` together with the `MnSymbol` package.

```latex
\documentclass{acmart}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}
\[\dot{v}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: the output]

Changing the document class to `article` solves it, as does removing `MnSymbol`.

Comment: acmart loads  newtxmath https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/567331/1090

Comment: What is the reason for using `MnSymbol`? It provides symbols that aren't compatible with Libertinus, the font used by `acmart`.

Comment: @egreg I am using several arrows and binary operations, and the lsem-rsem brackets.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In the post you linked the answer suggests that this is ok (assuming acmart loads before the package). I probably misunderstood you.

Comment: they are basically in conflict the ordering depends on specifics of \AtBeginDocument which I didn't trace. Basically you shouldn't use such a package making global changes to a publisher class. If really needed you can load the font and define specific symbols. @egreg has an answer on site about that I think

Comment: I found https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242115/extracting-overrightharpoon-from-mnsymbol?rq=1 but it is very cryptic. It doesn't explain what to do in general, just a particular example. [I posted a new question about this.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687933/what-is-the-process-of-extracting-a-symbol-from-mnsymbol)