# What is the process of extracting a symbol from MnSymbol

Tags: mnsymbol

It is often recommended to the particular symbol from `MnSymbol` that you require instead of importing the package entirely [such as the answer by @egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242115/extracting-overrightharpoon-from-mnsymbol?rq=1).

1. What is the general process of doing this?
2. What if I need several symbols?
3. Is there a difference, say, if I need an arrow vs. delimiters?
4. Not really a question, just a complaint: seems crazy to me that I need to do this just to get a few symbols from a package that offers them.

Comment: I suggest first read `fntguide.pdf` to learn something about math font. `stmaryrd` is designed better, it has a key `only`, but `MnSymbol` don't have.

Comment: About 4, what would you expect? That somebody already did write packages for all different sets of symbols that people might want? _That_ seems crazy to me.

Comment: packages setting up math typically want to get a consistent set of symbols, it seldom looks good if only an arrow or a delimiter or an integral is taken from a font and all other symbols from some other font. This is not crazy, it is more crazy that people think that you can load and mix lots of different font packages without getting a mess.